# Eclipse: Drop-down menu on wrong side

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

When Running Eclipse on my dual-monitor setup, the drop-down menu is somehow on the opposite screen everytime. How can I prevent this situation from happening?
[image]

Comment: I can't even see where it should be.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there is a property of dual screens in windows that lets you optionally treat each screen like it were its own screen (and not an extension of the other).  I could be wrong though.

Comment: What happens when Eclipse isn't straddling the two screens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure Maintain Display scaling is checked hope the below one will fix your problem.

[image]

Comment: How do I get to this menu in the first place?